# Return value -Java API design VS. C API

Tags: java, api

I used C a lot before and now use Java. I have a question of API design in JAVA. 
In C, I always use `int` as a meaningful return value, and put multiple objects(some of which will be changed) in arguments. e.g,

```
int foo(int x, int y, int *result)
{
     *result=x+y;
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

In Java, pass by reference seems to be vague, and it is good to put returned objects in argument? e.g,

```
Class Person{
   ...
}
```

Two APIs:

```
public Person bar()          // return value is the object
```

vs.

```
public int bar(Person p)     // return value is passed by reference
```

Moreover, how about changing multiple objects in one function? Return a list might not be graceful.

```
public int zoo(Person p, Alien x)   // both p and x will be changed
```

**EDIT1**

This question boils down to two ones.

1) If we want to change objects in one function, these objects should be passed in arguments(as mutable objects)?

2) How does the caller know the return status, by return code or others(like exceptions)?

Comment: "pass by reference seems to be vague" How so?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges; a functional language VS an object oriented language.

Comment: @Gimby C isn't a functional language. Do you mean imperative, perhaps? Or maybe procedural?

Comment: What do want to do with `Person p`? If fields of p shall be changed, I'd consider introducing a method on Person ( Person#bar() ) instead a function that is given a Person.

Comment: In Java it considered to be a good design practice to have immutable objects, therefore having method which will change the state of the passed object might be considered as a code smell.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major difference is that Java had exceptions, and exception handling, from the start. That means there is no need to return "SUCCESS". If it returns at all, rather than throwing an exception, it was successful.

Java does **not** have pass-by-reference. What it does have is pointers. When you call a method like `public int bar(Person p)`, `p` is a pointer to a `Person` object unless it is null.

Comment: thanks. You mean throwing exceptions captured by caller has the same effect of returning int value in C.

Comment: @frogcdcn Throwing exceptions allows much more flexible handling than the int status return strategy. You can put a sequence of related operations in the same try block, and deal with all the exceptions in its catch clauses. That makes the normal flow much cleaner than explicitly testing a return value after each call.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to replace try-catch with if-else. The former is simpler and concise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return multiple objects, you should probably define a class for the return value. There is a fair chance they are related and are secretly looking for a home to live together anyway. Another option is to use a `Pair` class (Apache commons lang) or a `List`, but that is messy and to be avoided.

You should avoid passing in arguments to be modified by reference as the semantics of parameter passing can differ for RPC type calls, even depending on container configuration (in other words, you are  not guaranteed to get a result returned as a parameter as it can end up being call-by-value).

As far as return codes go: you usually don't need them. Throw an exception if there is an error, otherwise it is successful. If you have different types of success, you might need to return a complex object or an object hierarchy. If you are returning some kind of integer status code it might indicate an anti pattern of some kind.